# Change the number data in file after manipulating it

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program about bank deposit. The data are inside the .txt file like this:

```
test101,1234,5000
```

where 'test101' is username, 1234 is password and 5000 is the Savings amount.

After I enter the amount, I'm stuck. I only know how to read the file.

This is my code:

```
accountfile = 'accounts.txt'
def login():
    loginUsername = input("Enter Username: ")
    loginPassword = input("Enter PASSWORD: ")
        
    with open(accountfile, "r+") as data:
        accounts = data.readlines()
        
    userfound = False
    for line in accounts:
        splitline = line.split(",")
        if loginUsername == splitline[0] and loginPassword == splitline[1]:
            userfound = True
            print("LOGGED IN")
            print("----------------------------------------")
                    
            depositAmount=float(input("Enter DEPOSIT AMOUNT: "))
            number = float(splitline[2])
                    
            number = number + depositAmount
            print("Your BALANCE is: ",number)
                    

            break
    return userfound
        
userfound = login()
if userfound:        
    print()
else:   
    print("Login FAILED")    
    print("----------------------------------------")
```

I already add the `splitlines[2]` and the new deposit amount. The problem is how to store the new amount for that user, back to the text file.

Comment: you want the result to be like this: username, password, saving amount, balance?

Comment: @PrakashDahal, OP is trying to add the deposit to the saving amount

Comment: @PrakashDahal  What I mean is add the value (e.g.  500) to the savings and change the value in txt file with the new updated savings amount

Comment: @Don'tAccept yes, add deposit to the existing

Comment: I don't think modifying the text file at a given index is possible, you can try rewriting the entire file after modifying the saving amount

Comment: @Don'tAccept i tried to rewrite but all the users data in the file was removed.

Comment: You need to keep the records of all other users as well.

Comment: Since you imply you have other users and you want to preserve their records in the file, you should add a couple of other user rows to your sample data, to test this. (To make sure you don't erase or corrupt their records).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are returning either `True` of `False`, you can simply add the rest were you check if `True/False` is returned

```
accountfile = 'accounts.txt'
def login():
    loginUsername = input("Enter Username: ")
    loginPassword = input("Enter PASSWORD: ")
        
    with open(accountfile, "r+") as data:
        accounts = data.readlines()
        
    userfound = False
    for line in accounts:
        global splitline
        splitline = line.split(",")
        if loginUsername == splitline[0] and loginPassword == splitline[1]:
            userfound = True
            global main
            main=line
            return userfound
        
userfound = login()
if userfound:        
    print("LOGGED IN")
    print("----------------------------------------")
            
    depositAmount=float(input("Enter DEPOSIT AMOUNT: "))
    number = float(splitline[2])
            
    number2 = number + depositAmount
    print("Your BALANCE is: ",number2)
    main2=main
    main2=main2.split(",")
    main2=main2[:2]+[str(number2)]
    main2=','.join(main2)
    
    with open(accountfile, 'r') as file :
      filedata = file.read()

    # Replace the target string
    filedata = filedata.replace(main,main2+"\n")

    # Write the file out again
    with open(accountfile, 'w') as file:
      file.write(filedata)
    print("DEPOSITED AMOUNT")
else:   
    print("Login FAILED")    
    print("----------------------------------------")
```

Sample:
accounts.txt

```
test101,1234,6000.0
test102,12334,5000.0
test103,123435,5000.0
test104,123445,74000.0
test105,12344,10000.0
a,b,100100.0
```

Running the main File

```
Enter Username: test102
Enter PASSWORD: 12334
LOGGED IN
----------------------------------------
Enter DEPOSIT AMOUNT: 3050
Your BALANCE is:  8050.0
DEPOSITED AMOUNT
```

accounts.txt

```
test101,1234,6000.0
test102,12334,8050.0test103,123435,5000.0
test104,123445,74000.0
test105,12344,10000.0
a,b,100100.0
```

Comment: @ Sujay im getting an error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 27, in <module>
    main2=main
NameError: name 'main' is not defined

Comment: Oh, @CarlmaloneMabiog, Sorry, I edited the question. Now it should work

Comment: No problem @CarlmaloneMabiog, happy to help

Comment: one last question  sir @Sujay , how to fix this b'coz when the program end, the file becomes these: carl,1234,9800.0test102,12334,5000.0 .. the second account goes up

Comment: @CarlmaloneMabiog, try ```filedata+"\n"```  when you write

Comment: Sir @Sujay nothing happened

Comment: @CarlmaloneMabiog, Here is the fix: ```filedata = filedata.replace(main,main2+"\n")```. Since a phrase is denoted by a ```"\n"``` when there is a new line, I forgot to add it. Hence you got that. But now, it is fixed.

Comment: Thank you for that again sir @Sujay !!

Comment: Most Welcome @CarlmaloneMabiog